# R: How do I create k subsets subject to a condition applied to k columns?

Tags: r, subset, multiple-columns

Example:

```
fdistr[ which(fdistm[,4]<=5),]
        zip      long      lat 1   2     3  4   5
32403 72756 -94.07141 36.34224 3 122 19401 51 704
32404 72757 -94.11565 36.37198 2 141 19546 45 740
32405 72758 -94.14622 36.30662 1 149 19578 30 724

fdistr[ which(fdistm[,5]<=5),]
        zip      long      lat   1 2     3   4   5
32312 72601 -93.09345 36.23698 181 1 16548 328 354


fdistr[ which(fdistm[,6]<=5),]
        zip      long      lat     1     2 3     4     5
13271 30529 -83.46842 34.21042 16867 15514 1 17241 12593
```

How do I loop over k columns to create k subsets?

Thanks!

Comment: Now @MarcMoroccoholic is your turn to accept an answer and prevent people from further useless clicks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lapply` as follows:

```
k <- 5
subsets <- lapply(3 + 1:k, function(x, i, m) x[x[, i] <= m, ], x = fdistm, m = 5)
```

It will return a list of `k` subsets.

Comment: Guess, I'll go out for a beer. flodel is on the case.

Comment: Flodel - Thanks for the neat solution. Is there a way to flatten each subset by including comma delimited zip codes with the sums (totals) of the continuous variables within each list of zip codes?

Answer (score 0):

Use `apply` and assuming your dataframe is fdistm(Not tested)

`fdistm[apply(fdistm[, -1], MARGIN = 1, function(x) all(x <=5)), ]`

Note:applies to all except the first